# Conflict in Merging a file which has been deleted from branch1 into another branch2 in Git-Hub

Tags: git, github, git-gui

Using GIT GUI to resolve merge conflicts, I deleted one file1 in branch1 and same file1 has some changes in branch2.

When merging branch1 into branch2, get conflicts in file1, I deleted file1 in branch1 manually, but it's still not allowing me to commit and push.

Comment: So resolve the conflict. Decide if you want to keep the modified file from the branch that modified it, or if you want it to stay deleted.

Comment: It is correct that git stops here because there isn't an inherently right decision that git could just automatically do. As such, you have no option but to resolve the conflict by *deciding* how this should be handled. If your stance is "But I deleted the file, why is that a conflict?" Well, you also modified the file on that other branch, are you saying those changes are worthless? If so then why did you do them? If your team fixed a bug in one branch and you deleted the entire class in another, the correct handling of this *might* be to move the fix somewhere else. So, manual resolution.